# Deserialize CCTray Content XML to list of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, serialization, xml-parsing

I am trying to deserialize the XML contents of the CCTray.xml from my build server with c#.

Tje XML content has a parent 'Projects' element with an array of 'Project' elements below.  Each project element has multiple attributes.

I created a Projects model:

```
[XmlRoot("Projects")]
public class ProjectCollection
{
    public ProjectCollection() { Projects = new List<Project>(); }

    [XmlArray("Project")]
    public List<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

And a model for each project:

```
public class Project
{
    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Activity")]
    public string Activity { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("lastBuildStatus")]
    public string LastBuildStatus { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("lastBuildLabel")]
    public string LastBuildLabel { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("WebUrl")]
    public string WebUrl { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("LastBuildTime")]
    public DateTimeOffset LastBuildTime { get; set; }
}
```

I try and deserialize the response from HttpClient like:

```
var xmlStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ProjectCollection));
var projects = (ProjectCollection)serializer.Deserialize(xmlStream);
```

The result of which is an empty ProjectCollection object.

I'm know I must be mapping the XML to my object incorrectly, but I can't see where its wrong.

A sample of the XML being returned is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Projects>
    <Project name="Company.Project1.Api :: Build" activity="Sleeping" lastBuildStatus="Success" lastBuildLabel="1.0.0.203" lastBuildTime="2017-03-21T10:56:53" webUrl="http://build-company.com:8153/go/pipelines/Company.Project1.Api/203/Build/1" />
    <Project name="Company.Project2.Api :: Build :: Build" activity="Sleeping" lastBuildStatus="Success" lastBuildLabel="1.0.0.203" lastBuildTime="2017-03-21T10:56:53" webUrl="http://build-company.com:8153/go/tab/build/detail/Company.Project2.Api/203/Build/1/Build" />
</Projects>
```

What do I need to do deserialize this XML to my object correctly?

Thanks

Comment: Use RestSharp it'll be more easy to deserialize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class structure does not fit the data you get. With your class structure the XML struture should look different. The root needs an other element called `Project`. This element contains your items.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Projects>
    <Project>
        <Project name="Company.Project1.Api :: Build" activity="Sleeping" lastBuildStatus="Success" lastBuildLabel="1.0.0.203" lastBuildTime="2017-03-21T10:56:53" webUrl="http://build-company.com:8153/go/pipelines/Company.Project1.Api/203/Build/1" />
        <Project name="Company.Project2.Api :: Build :: Build" activity="Sleeping" lastBuildStatus="Success" lastBuildLabel="1.0.0.203" lastBuildTime="2017-03-21T10:56:53" webUrl="http://build-company.com:8153/go/tab/build/detail/Company.Project2.Api/203/Build/1/Build" />
    </Project>
</Projects>
```

To get the data, based on your XML structure, correctly you have to use a simple root like

```
[XmlRoot("Projects")]
public class ProjectCollection : List<Project>
{
}
```

Also you need to update all properties of your `Project`. The XML `Project` does not have any elements, only XML attributes are used to store data. This means you need to use `XmlAttribute` instead of `XmlElement`. Also note that the names are case sensitive, which is also not correct in your code.

```
[XmlAttribute("name")]
public string Name { get; set; }
//...
```

Comment: Great thanks, spot on answer.  For completeness I also had to change the DatetimeOffset to DateTime